# Write each 200 lines to new file in PHP

Tags: php, fwrite

My code:

```
$file = "read_file.txt";
$file_path =  "write.txt";
$count = 0;
$counter = 1;

$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
if($count == 200){
   $file_path =  "write_".$counter++."txt";
   $count == 0;
}
   $count++;
   $file_handle = fopen($file_path, "w");
   $file_contents = $line;
   fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
   fclose($file_handle);
}
```

I want to write every new 200 lines read from the file into new files (in other words to divide the whole file into 200lines/file)  but everytime i get one line into new file can anyone help me out where im doing wrong

Comment: you never reset $count

Comment: wouldn't `split -l 200 read_file.txt write.txt` be easier (faster probably)

Comment: thats not the issue i had the reset code just forgot to paste here, As you posted the suggestion so atleast 200 lines should be write to a file ? but i said every time it writes only one line to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening a new file for each line which overwrites the last which is why you are only getting one line per file. This is likely not the way you want to.

Instead, loop through and get groups of 200 lines, and then write. This means a 1001 line file will have 6 writes, instead of 1001. This way will be **MUCH** faster than the other methods

```
$count = 0;
$counter = 1;
$file_lines = '';

$lines = file("read_file.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $file_lines .= $line . "\n";
   $count++;
   if($count == 200) {
      $file_handle = fopen("write_".$counter++."txt", "w+");
      fwrite($file_handle, $file_lines);
      fclose($file_handle);       
      $count = 0;
      $file_lines = '';
   }
}
```

**EDIT**: Darren's suggestion for `array_chunk` would be much better for variable length arrays

Comment: best answer thank you man by the way i tried everyone but urs worked thanx mate :)

Comment: You get my up-vote for a well-worded answer and a more complete, rounded solution compared to the other answers!

Answer (score 1):

You're looping badly, why don't you just chunk your `$lines` array into groups of 200 (*as you require*) and then write them to separate files....

```
$lines = file($file);
$groups = array_chunk($lines, 200);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $file_path = "write_".$counter++.".txt";
    $file_handle = fopen($file_path, "w");
    fwrite($file_handle, implode("\n", $group));
}
```

<sup>*Reference: [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk)*</sup>

[Here's an example of how it chunks](http://www.tehplayground.com/#PXAY2BGJz)

Comment: Though, shouldn't you implode your `$group` with `\n`'s before you write because `$group` is an array, not string for `fwrite`

Comment: @CarlK Good spot! forgot about that!

Answer (score 0):

This as below. Your files writing should be putting in the if condition.

```
$file = "read_file.txt";
$file_path =  "write.txt";
$count = 0;
$counter = 1;

$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   if($count == 0){ //Open a file and start writing.
    $file_path =  "write_".$counter++."txt";
    $file_handle = fopen($file_path, "w");
   }
   $file_contents = $line;
   fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents); //Append into the file

   if($count == 200){ //When it reach 200 close the file
    fclose($file_handle);
    $count = 0; //reset it to 0
   }
   $count++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. Only subtle changes needed to be made for your code to function well.

- `$count = 0;` was changed to `$count = 1;`
- In `$file_path = "write_" . $counter++ . ".txt";` line `".txt"` was used instead of `"txt"`
- `$count == 0` was changed to `$count = 0`
- I split files after 4 lines for ease of testing

Code:

```
<?php
$file = "read_file.txt";
$file_path =  "write.txt";
$count = 1;
$counter = 1;

$lines = file($file);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo "file path is $file_path\n";
    if($count == 4){
        print "reaching here\n";
        $file_path =  "write_". $counter++ . ".txt";
        $count = 0;
    }
   $count++;
   $file_handle = fopen($file_path, "w");
   $file_contents = $line;
   fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
   fclose($file_handle);
}
?>
```